# Why javaDoc asks to create a java file with an invalid name (package-info.java)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javadoc, intellij-14

I'm using **InteliJ Idea 14**. And for the use of **javaDocs** I'm trying to create the `package-info.java` (Not a valid name but it's the requirement), but the  IDE won't allow to create a new Java file with that name. It says `This is not a valid Java qualified name`.

Anyway I could create it as a new File with the name "package-info.java".

Is it okay to do  like that ? or is there any other way ?

And why javaDoc asks to create a java file with an invalid name ?

Comment: You mean update Intelij-Idea ?

Comment: But why the down votes ? Appreciate if someone can give a reason

Comment: Perhaps because you didn't research your Q before asking.  If you want to really understand *why* a language feature the way it is, the *first place* to look is the language's specification.  This applies to any PL, not just Java.  And in this case, the JLS explains *precisely* why it was designed that way.

Comment: The linked dup Q&A answers all of your questions.  "Is it OK?", "Are there alternatives?" and "Why?".  (The answer to "Why" is to read the rationale in the JLS ... using the link that the top Answer helpfully gives you.)

Comment: @StephenC That package.html question is not asking the same thing and the answer there is not a direct answer to this question. You should have posted an answer here with the link and copy of the JLS "7.4.1. Named Packages" footnote about package-info.java and not marked this as a duplicate.
Also, in the future, you could consider any question that can be answered by reading specifications to be a question asking to be pointed to the relevant location in the specs. Sifting through manuals is tough, especially for newbies. If you know where something can be found, be helpful and point it out.

Answer (score 4):

See documentation: [IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2 Help - Creating Packages and package-info Files](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-packages-and-package-info-files.html):

> To create a package-info.java file, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Open the Project tool window (e.g. View | Tool Windows | Project).
> 2. Select the package for which you want to create a package-info file.
> 3. Do one of the following:
>
>    - Select `File` | `New` | `package-info.java`.
>    - Select `New` | `package-info.java` from the context menu.
>    - Press `Alt+Insert` and select `package-info.java`.

Comment: Yeah. Thats what I did then. Thanks for the tips. But why ? And why javaDoc asks to create a java file with an invalid name ?

Comment: @prime Because that way it's guaranteed to not clash with a class name. See Java Language Specification [§7.4.1. Named Packages](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.4.1): *The sole annotated `package` declaration, if it exists, is placed in a source file called `package-info.java` in the directory containing the source files for the package. This file does not contain the source for a class called `package-info.java`; indeed it would be illegal for it to do so, as `package-info` is not a legal identifier.*